# How big can the argument to Perl's rand be?

Tags: perl, random

`rand(n)` returns a number between `0` and `n`. Will `rand` work as expected, with regard to "randomness", for all arguments up to the integer limit on my platform?

Comment: For more information, I found this intriguing: http://wellington.pm.org/archive/200704/randomness/index.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is going to depend on your [`randbits`](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/random) value:

> rand calls your system's random number generator (or whichever one was
>      compiled into your copy of Perl). For this discussion, I'll call that
>      generator RAND to distinguish it from rand, Perl's function. RAND produces
>      an integer from 0 to 2**randbits - 1, inclusive, where randbits is a small
>      integer. To see what it is in your perl, use the command 'perl
>      -V:randbits'. Common values are 15, 16, or 31.
>
> When you call rand with an argument arg, perl takes that value as an
>      integer and calculates this value.
>
> ```
>                         arg * RAND
>           rand(arg) = ---------------
>                         2**randbits
> ```
>
> This value will always fall in the range required.
>
> ```
>           0  <=  rand(arg)  < arg
> ```
>
> But as arg becomes large in comparison to 2**randbits, things become
>      problematic. Let's imagine a machine where randbits = 15, so RAND ranges
>      from 0..32767. That is, whenever we call RAND, we get one of 32768
>      possible values. Therefore, when we call rand(arg), we get one of 32768
>      possible values.

Comment: To access randbits from within perl, `use Config; print $Config::Config{'randbits'}`.  randbits is 15 for MSWin32, 48 for most other platforms.

Comment: @ysth There's also perl -V:randbits

Comment: Yes, that's mentioned in the answer, but it would be a little silly to use that from within perl...

Comment: This was driving me crazy. For example this code never gets out of the while loop on Activeperl on Windows: perl -e "while( int(rand(65536)) != 1 ) {$i++}; print $i;" 
but any value less than 65536 does

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the number of bits used by your system's (pseudo)random number generator. You can find this value via

```
perl -V:randbits
```

or within a program via

```
use Config;
my $randbits = $Config{randbits};
```

`rand` can generate 2^randbits distinct random numbers. While you can generate numbers larger than 2^randbits, you can't generate all of the integer values in the range [0, N) when N > 2^randbits.

Values of N which aren't a power of two can also be problematic, as the distribution of (integer truncated) random values won't quite be flat. Some values will be slightly over-represented, others slightly under-represented.

It's worth noting that randbits is a paltry 15 on Windows. This means you can only get 32768 (2**15) distinct values. You can improve the situation by making multiple calls to `rand` and combining the values:

```
use Config;
use constant RANDBITS => $Config{randbits};
use constant RAND_MAX => 2**RANDBITS;

sub double_rand {
    my $max = shift || 1;
    my $iv  =
          int rand(RAND_MAX) << RANDBITS
        | int rand(RAND_MAX);
    return $max * ($iv / 2**(2*RANDBITS));
}
```

Assuming randbits = 15, `double_rand` mimics randbits = 30, providing 1073741824 (2**30) possible distinct values. This alleviates (but can never eliminate) both of the problems mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about big random integers and whether it is possible to get them. It should be noted that the concatenation of two random integers is also a random integer. So if your system, for any reason, cannot go beyond 999999999999, then just write

```
$bigrand = int(rand(999999999999)).int(rand(999999999999));
```

and you'll get a random integer of (maximally) twice the length.

(Actually this is not a numeric answer to the question “how big a rand number can be” but rather the answer “you can get as big as you want, just concatenate small numbers”.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What you are suggesting as an answer is covered by one of the two existing answers, and covered rather better by the answer.  If you were going to use your technique, you would need to ensure that the second part of the number is prefixed by enough zeroes.  You've chosen 12 digits in the example, which is likely to cause some issues; 9 digits would be safer.  You would probably need to use `sprintf("%d%09d", rand(999_999_999), rand(999_999_999))` to generate the string.  Even that might be problematic on Windows; see the other answers for why.