# Why does rand($val) not warn when $val > 2 ** randbits?

Tags: perl

I'm using [`Strawberry Perl`](http://strawberryperl.com/) `v5.16.2` to construct some fake data using repeated calls to [`int rand 1_000_000`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html).  After, quite a bit of befuddlement, I discovered that because my perl's `randbits=15`, the above expression will only return `2**15` or `32768` possible values.

```
>perl -V:randbits
randbits='15';
```

My questions are:

- Why does [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) not return a warning when someone attempts to use `rand $val` where `$val > 2 ** randbits`?
- Why does [`perldoc rand`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html) not mention this issue at all?  There is an addendum about how `"rand() is not cryptographically secure"`.  I believe this also deserves an addendum with suggested alternative solutions as well.

**Setup**

I'm attempting to create some fake data to test an algorithm for sorting large amounts of data with an average of 20 duplicates.  This worked fine for 1,000 and 10,000 entries, but when I jumped to 1 million, I discovered that I was missing a lot of unique values.

This seemed a statistical improbability.  The probability `p` that a specific integer less than 1 million would not be chosen in 20 million pulls is `(999_999/1_000_000) ** 20_000_000` or `2.06e-9`.  So the probability that any integer wouldn't be chosen is `.2%`.

I quickly hacked together another script to confirm that there wasn't a flaw in my fake data generator:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(sum max min);

our $max_count = 1_000;

my %count;

while (1) {
    my $val = int rand 1_000_000;
    last if ++$count{$val} > $max_count;
}

my $sum = sum values %count;
my $max = max values %count;
my $min = min values %count;
my $count = scalar keys %count;

print "$sum interations.  $count integers of expected 1mil with min $min, max $max\n";
```

Outputs:

```
28,958,579 interations.  32768 integers of expected 1mil with min 772, max 1001
```

Obviously, `32,768` was a huge red flag being a power of `2`, so doing a quick google for [`"perl rand does maximum 32768 integers"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=perl+rand+does+maximum+32768+integers) returned the following useful resources:

- [`What is wrong with perl's antique random number generator`](http://wellington.pm.org/archive/200704/randomness/#slide8)
- [`How big can the argument to Perl's rand be? - Stack Overflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993439/how-big-can-the-argument-to-perls-rand-be)

The former was a great resource for discussing all the different aspects to this issue, and provided to drop in replacements for `rand` with [`use Math::Random::MT qw(rand);`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Random::MT) and [`use Math::Random::MT::Auto qw(rand);`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Random::MT::Auto).

The SO post provided [`an answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12166633/1733163) that included a solution that didn't require a new module installation by just calling `rand` twice for more bits.

```
use Config;
use constant RANDBITS => $Config{randbits};
use constant RAND_MAX => 2**RANDBITS;

sub double_rand {
    my $max = shift || 1;
    my $iv  =
          int rand(RAND_MAX) << RANDBITS
        | int rand(RAND_MAX);
    return $max * ($iv / 2**(2*RANDBITS));
}
```

Fortunately, both of these solved my initial problem.  To recap though, I'm curious ...

- Is there a better drop in replacement for `rand`?
- Why isn't there a two sentence addendum in `perldoc rand` mentioning this issue?
- Why does `warnings` not warn for values greater than `2**randbits`?  If someone wanted to ignore the warnings, there could be a `no warnings 'rand'` call or simply call rand with no value: `val * rand`.
- Did I install Strawberry Perl wrong to end up with such a low randbits?  Is there a way to just up that value?  And is it the user's responsibility to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: Should it warn for rand(1000)? Cause that's biased too.

Comment: Re "Did I install Strawberry Perl wrong to end up with such a low randbits?", No, it's what the C library provides.

Comment: Re "Is there a better drop in replacement for rand?", As mentioned in the docs, CPAN provides cryptographic-quality random number generators.

Comment: @ikegami I'd argue that the `rand` docs already mention the biased nature of `rand(1000)` in the addendum about not being _"cryptographically secure"_  What is a false claim is the very first sentence of the docs _"Returns a random fractional number greater than or equal to 0 and less than the value of EXPR"_  I don't expect perfect randomness, but that does imply a lot more than 32768 possible values between 0 and EXPR.  But that is mentioned nowhere in the docs.  Anyway, "thanks" for the quick feedback.  I'll ping PM about this sometime tomorrow.

Comment: That's not really a false claim, is it?  (Unless your issue's with the word `random`.)

Comment: @JimDavis Yes, I have issues with _"random fractional number"_ for all values of `EXPR`.  If `EXPR < 1000`, I can see that claim being "true enough".  However, if `EXPR = 32768`, then it's literally random INTEGERS.  And if `EXPR = 4_096_000`?  then it's literally random multiples of 125.  This is far from the intent communicated by that first sentence, and there's absolutely nothing in the documentation that mentions this.

Comment: @Miller, that's a separate issue. `rand(1000)` is biased because 1000 is not a power of 2.

Comment: Doc changes are moot anyway, since drand48 being packaged with Perl now for systems with awful clib rands.

Comment: Well, when you use the `rand` builtin, you are relying on the C runtime library. While this problem with on Windows is particularly glaring, there is no reason to assume the default PRNG on another system does not have another more subtle pitfall. See also http://blog.nu42.com/2010/09/be-vary-of-using-built-in-rng-for.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time to upgrade perl.

Starting with [`perl v5.20 - perldelta`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RJBS/perl-5.20.0/pod/perldelta.pod#rand-now-uses-a-consistent-random-number-generator)

> - `rand` now uses a consistent random number generator
>
>   Previously perl would use a platform specific random number generator, varying between the libc rand(), random() or drand48().
>
>   This meant that the quality of perl's random numbers would vary from platform to platform, from the 15 bits of rand() on Windows to 48-bits on POSIX platforms such as Linux with drand48().
>
>   Perl now uses its own internal drand48() implementation on all platforms. This does not make perl's `rand` cryptographically secure. [perl #115928]

I still wish that older versions of perl would give a warning when using `rand` when the value is greater than `2 ** randbits`, but this is the best result I could hope for.

Will still have to be watchful of other programmers on Windows and continue recommending alternatives such as [`use Math::Random::MT qw(rand);`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math%3a%3aRandom%3a%3aMT) if they're unable to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?q=random) there seems to be some appropriate resources. Math::BigInt::Random seems a good one for very large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For non-cryptographic purposes, use [Math::Random::MT](https://metacpan.org/Math%3a%3aRandom%3a%3aMT). [The Mersenne Twister PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) has nice properties.

You can use the function interface as a drop in replacement for the `rand` builtin:

#### Function-oriented interface:

```
use Math::Random::MT qw(srand rand irand);
# now use srand() and rand() as you usually do in Perl
```