# Take random substrings from genome data

Tags: perl

I am trying to use the substring function to take random 21 base sequences from a genome in fasta format. Below is the start of the sequence:

FILE1 data:

```
>gi|385195117|emb|HE681097.1| Staphylococcus aureus subsp. aureus HO 5096 0412 complete genome
CGATTAAAGATAGAAATACACGATGCGAGCAATCAAATTTCATAACATCACCATGAGTTTGGTCCGAAGCATGAGTGTTTACAATGTTTGAATACCTTATACAGTTCTTATACATAC
```

I have tried adapting a previous answer to use while reading my file and i'm not getting any error messages, just no output! The code hopefully prevents there being any overlap of sequences, though the chances of that are very small anyway.

Code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $outputfile = "/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/randomoutput.txt";

open FILE1, "/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/EMRSA-15.fasta";

open( OUTPUTFILE, ">$outputfile" );

while ( my $line = <FILE1> ) {
    if ( $line =~ /^([ATGCN]+)/ ) {

        my $genome = $1;
        my $size   = 21;
        my $count  = 5;
        my $mark   = 'X';

        if ( 2 * $size * $count - $size - $count >= length($genome) ) {

            my @substrings;
            while ( @substrings < $count ) {
                my $pos = int rand( length($genome) - $size + 1 );
                push @substrings, substr( $genome, $pos, $size, $mark x $size )
                    if substr( $genome, $pos, $size ) !~ /\Q$mark/;
                for my $random (@substrings) {
                    print OUTPUTFILE "random\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, for one, you're printing the string `random` instead of the contents of variable `$random`.

Comment: Cheers, i hadn't noticed that but i still have the same problem!

Comment: @EdTickle: If you want *non-overlapping* sequences then I need to thinik again. What sort of size is your real data? Genome size and number, subsequence size, and count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the neatest ways to select a random start point is to shuffle a list of all possible start points and select the first few -- as many as you need.

It's also best practice to use the *three-parameter* form of `open`, and *lexical file handles*.

The loop in this example starts much like your own -- picking up the genomes using a regex. The subsequences of length `$size` can start anywhere from zero up to `$len_genome - $size`, so the program generates a list of all these starting points, shuffles them using the utility function from [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::Util), and puts them in `@start_points`.

Finally, if there are sufficient start points to form `$count` different subsequences, then they are printed, using `substr` in the print statement.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use List::Util qw/ shuffle /;

my $outputfile = '/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/randomoutput.txt';

open my $in_fh,  '<', '/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/EMRSA-15.fasta';
open my $out_fh, '>', $outputfile;

my $size       = 21;
my $count      = 5;

while (my $line = <$in_fh>) {
   next unless $line =~ /^([ATGCN]+)/;

   my $genome     = $1;
   my $len_genome = length $genome;

   my @start_points = shuffle(0 .. $len_genome-$size);
   next unless @start_points >= $count;
   print substr($genome, $_, 21), "\n" for @start_points[0 .. $count-1];
}
```

**output**

```
TACACGATGCGAGCAATCAAA
GTTTACAATGTTTGAATACCT
ACATCACCATGAGTTTGGTCC
ATAACATCACCATGAGTTTGG
GGTCCGAAGCATGAGTGTTTA
```

Comment: @EdTickle: I'm concerned that this solution isn't what you wanted. It allows *overlapping* subsequences and I think that's wrong?

Comment: That works a treat, thank you for your help! Overlapping sequences isn't a huge issue, the chances of 1000-21bp sequences overlapping in a 3 billion genome aren't that high, and won't affect my results anyway!

Comment: It means you're keeping a 3 billion element array just to pick the first 1000 elements though. Have you tried it on the real data? Do you have 64-bit Perl?

Comment: I have tried it using the full genome and it runs fine and immediately too. I don't believe i do, i'm on os-x.

Comment: @EdTickle: Are you sure you're not working on just one-line chunks of the genome? If you want to process all the based pairs at once then the individual lines in the FASTA file need to be concatenated. Unless you have a 3billion-character lineinstead of the 120-character one you show?!

Comment: This genome has a 3 billion character line yes! It is identical to my sample data above but that only has the first 120 characters of it, i will be working on files with multiple genomes in that format though. These substrings are simply acting as controls, i am looking at repeats around the 11th base of each one (which is my next task!).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend saving all possible positions for a substring in an array.  That way you can remove possibilities after each substring to prevent overlap:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $infile  = "/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/EMRSA-15.fasta";
my $outfile = "/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/randomoutput.txt";

my $size       = 21;
my $count      = 5;
my $min_length = ( $count - 1 ) * ( 2 * $size - 1 ) + $size;

#open my $infh,  '<', $infile;
#open my $outfh, '>', $outfile;
my $infh  = \*DATA;
my $outfh = \*STDOUT;

while ( my $line = <$infh> ) {
    next unless $line =~ /^([ATGCN]+)/;

    my $genome = $1;

    # Need a long enough sequence for multiple substrings with no overlap
    if ( $min_length > length $genome ) {
        warn "Line $., Genome too small:  Must be $min_length, not ", length($genome), "\n";
        next;
    }

    # Save all possible positions for substrings in an array.  This enables us
    # to remove possibilities after each substring to prevent overlap.
    my @pos = ( 0 .. length($genome) - 1 - ( $size - 1 ) );

    for ( 1 .. $count ) {
        my $index = int rand @pos;
        my $pos   = $pos[$index];

        # Remove from possible positions
        my $min = $index - ( $size - 1 );
        $min = 0 if $min < 0;
        splice @pos, $min, $size + $index - $min;

        my $substring = substr $genome, $pos, $size;

        print $outfh "$pos - $substring\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
>gi|385195117|emb|HE681097.1| Staphylococcus aureus subsp. aureus HO 5096 0412 complete genome
CGATTAAAGATAGAAATACACGATGCGAGCAATCAAATTTCATAACATCACCATGAGTTTGGTCCGAAGCATGAGTGTTTACAATGTTTGAATACCTTATACAGTTCTTATACATACCGATTAAAGATAGAAATACACGATGCGAGCAATCAAA
CGATTAAAGATAGAAATACACGATGCGAGCAATCAAATTTCATAACATCACCATGAGTTTGGTCCGAAGCATGAGTGTTTACAATGTTTGAATACCTTATACAGTTCTTATACATACCGATTAAAGATAGAAATACACGATGCGAGCAATCAAATTTCATAACATCACCATGAGTTTGGTCCGAAGCATGAGTGTTTACAATGTTTGAATACCTTATACAGTTCTTATACATAC
```

Outputs:

```
Line 2, Genome too small:  Must be 185, not 154
101 - CAGTTCTTATACATACCGATT
70 - ATGAGTGTTTACAATGTTTGA
6 - AAGATAGAAATACACGATGCG
38 - TTCATAACATCACCATGAGTT
182 - GAAGCATGAGTGTTTACAATG
```

#### Alternative method for large genomes

You mentioned in a comment that genome may be 2 gigs in size.  If that's the case then it's possible that there won't be enough memory to have an array of all possible positions.

Your original approach of substituting a fake character for each chosen substring would work in that case.  The following is how I would do it, using `redo`:

```
    for ( 1 .. $count ) {
        my $pos = int rand( length($genome) - ( $size - 1 ) );
        my $str = substr $genome, $pos, $size;

        redo if $str =~ /X/;

        substr $genome, $pos, $size, 'X' x $size;

        print $outfh "$pos - $str\n";
    }
```

Also note, that if your genome really is that big, then you must also be wary of the randbits setting of your Perl version:

```
$ perl -V:randbits
randbits='48';
```

For some Windows versions, the randbits setting was just 15, therefore only returning 32,000 possible random values: [Why does rand($val) not warn when $val > 2 ** randbits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22772578/1733163)

Comment: Isn't `length($genome) - 1 - ( $size - 1 )` == `length($genome) - $size`?  That said, it beats my version's continued thrashing about until it finds something that fits (which could conceivably take a *long* time on big strings).

Comment: Yes, it is.  However, I purposefully put it in a longer form because it exposed what was going on mathematically.  I appreciated the fact that my code showed `( $size - 1 )` in two places, because that value was needed for the same reason.  If I had simplified the expression, that wouldn't be as apparent.

Comment: @EdTickle The test data that you provided wasn't actually long enough.  To be able to find 5 random non-overlapping sequences of 21 characters, one needs a string that is 205 characters long.  Your test data was only 117 characters, so I doubled it.  My suggestion: instead of skipping if the data isn't long enough, throw a warning first.  I suspect that is why you aren't getting any output, because if you run my script as is, it works.

Comment: That's strange, i even tried pasting your data into my input file and i still don't get any results!

Comment: Thank you for providing another method! The file is only 2.8mb, but i am still not getting any results, i also get an error message of "readline() on unopened filehandle DATA at ./random.pl line 18." if that is of any use when i run your original program. Thank you for your continued help, i really don't know what is going wrong!

Comment: If that is the error that you get, then you did not copy and paste my ENTIRE program, including the text below `__DATA__`.

Comment: I'ev just realised what ther OP meant. Unfortunately you can't do things this way and get an even distribution, because the position of later samples depends on where earlier ones ended. The only way is *either* to list *all* sets of N non-overlapping subsequences and randomly select as many as you need (which is what I coded, but I didn'tr realise the non-overlapping things), *or* to spin repeatedly generating random sets of N subsequences, and rejecting them until you find a set that doesn't overlap.

Comment: That does now work perfectly, apologies i forgot to un-hash the part which used my original file handles. Thanks again!

Comment: @Borodin Yes, I believe my solution is probably what is actually desired, for non-overlapping substrings.  However, I suspect that he wasn't aware of how to turn it from testing mode to live by switching out how the filehandles were being created with the two commented out lines.  *shrug*

Comment: @Miller: I don't see how a character index up to 3E9 can be kept without using `bignum` or some such.

Comment: @Borodin Normal integers have enough precision for `9E15 + 1` on my system, so I don't see how just 3 billion would be a problem?  Either way, the OP corrected that the file is only 2.8 mb and not 2.8 gb

Comment: @Miller: That's an odd number. It's about 37 bits. The maximum signed 32-bit integer os 0x7FFFFFFF, which is 2.1E9 or 2.1 billion, hence my concern about 3 billion. But if the OP has changed this to 3MB instead then there's no problem. Even a Perl program on my Android tablet will accommodate and shuffle that many numbers in a couple seconds!

Comment: @Borodin Agreed.  Yeah, my primary system is apparently 64bit.  However, perl randomly decides to put things in scientific notation when it passes 16 digits.  Dunno why, but not really that important since if I needed greater precision I could just use bignum like you said.

Answer (score 0):

I found it more effective to move the output `for` loop outside the inner `while`, and to add a condition to the `while` such that `$genome` must contain a `$size`-long chunk that hasn't already been partly selected.

Just because you've got a string that's 117 characters long doesn't mean you'll find 5 random non-overlapping chunks.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $outputfile = "/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/randomoutput.txt";

open FILE1, "/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/EMRSA-15.fasta";

open( OUTPUTFILE, ">$outputfile" );

while ( my $line = <FILE1> ) {
    if ( $line =~ /^([ATGCN]+)/ ) {
        my $genome = $1;
        my $size   = 21;
        my $count  = 5;
        my $mark   = 'X';

        if ( 2 * $size * $count - $size - $count >= length($genome) ) {
            my @substrings;
            while ( @substrings < $count
                and $genome =~ /[ATGCN]{$size}/ ) { # <- changed this
                my $pos = int rand( length($genome) - $size + 1 );
                push @substrings, substr( $genome, $pos, $size, $mark x $size )
                    if substr( $genome, $pos, $size ) !~ /\Q$mark/;
            }
            # v- changed this
            print OUTPUTFILE "$_\n" for @substrings;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The string is actually 2.8 billion characters long, i just thought it best to not paste it all in! Thank you for your help but i still don't get an output with this script..

Comment: Does the program stop running, or does it just continue producing no output until interrupted?

Comment: The program finishes running but doesn't output any information.